# Android studio 3.1.2 don't support ndk-build

Tags: android-studio, ndk-build

I'm using Android studio 3.1.2.In the official document ([向您的项目添加 C 和 C++ 代码](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code))

there isn't the way to use ndk-build.It seems prefer CMake.And when I use ndk-build ,config like below:
build.gradle at module level:

```
  compileSdkVersion 25
  defaultConfig{
   ndk {
        moduleName "telephone"
        cFlags "-fexceptions"
        ldLibs "log","z","m"

        stl "stlport_static"
        abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
       // path "$projectDir/jni/Android.mk"
       arguments "NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=$projectDir/jni/Application.mk"
       abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "armeabi","arm64-v8a","x86"
       cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"
     }
    }
   }
   sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ["src/main/jniLibs"]
        jni.srcDirs = ["src/main/jni"]
    }
   }
   buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
```

and Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := addcomputer
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := src/main/jni/addcomputer-jni.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

and Application.mk:

```
APP_ABI:=armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
APP_STL:=stlport_shared
APP_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions
```

But no matter how I change the configuration, the build behavior returns an error like this:

```
    Error: Your project contains C++ files but it is not using a supported 
   native build system.
   Consider using CMake or ndk-build integration. For more information, go to:
    https://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/add-native-code.html
   Alternatively, you can use the experimental plugin:
    https://developer.android.com/r/tools/experimental-plugin.html
```

And to reference this official webpage[ndk-build](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/ndk-build)
I have installed GNU Make 3.81,and export GNUMAKE, but didn't work.
I have found many reference material on the internet,although I configure like they said, but error came still.I don't know what to do.I need to use Android.mk and ndk-build.Because this webpage said:[Generating C++ Binder Interfaces with aidl-cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/tools/aidl/+/brillo-m10-dev/docs/aidl-cpp.md)

Anyone can help?Please.

Comment: I found that there are several problems in this configuration:1.the module name in Android.mk is different from that in build.gradle;I have fixed that problem.And then ,various problem came.But I finally fixed them.So I should change the title of this quection because Android studio 3.1.2 does support ndk-build.Just some config error......

Comment: What you do, I have this same probleme